# Bind Rows Repeatedly in to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: screenshot]

When I insert `@RoleID`, `@IsActive`, `@PermissionRoleID` this also inserted continuously. I want these 3 columns first time only next won't. How can I achieve that?

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in addGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("chkboxaddView") as CheckBox);
            CheckBox chkRow1 = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("chkboxaddEdit") as CheckBox);
            string aaa = row.Cells[0].Text;

            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                con.Open();

                var View = chkRow.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var Edit = chkRow1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var addchkboxisactive = chkaddisactive.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var editaddchkboxisactive = chkboxisactive.Checked ? 1 : 0;

                string sqlcmd = "select AccesspageID From AccessPages where pages='" + row.Cells[0].Text + "'";

                SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, con);
                cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var result = cmdd.ExecuteScalar();

                string query = "add3tables";         // Stored procedure name 

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);  //creating  SqlCommand  object
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  //here we declaring command type as stored Procedure

                // adding paramerters to  SqlCommand below 
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtaddrolename.Text.ToString());
                string unique_string = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID ", unique_string);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive ", addchkboxisactive);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionRoleID ", unique_string);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@View ", View);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edit ", Edit);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionAccessoageID ", result);

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

            if (chkRow1.Checked == false)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    this.ModalPopupExtender2.Hide();
    BindGridview();
}
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE add3tables
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @RoleID nvarchar(50),
    @PermissionRoleID nvarchar(50),
    @IsActive bit,
    @View bit,
    @Edit bit,
    @PermissionAccessoageID nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into Roles values(@Name, @RoleID, @IsActive)

    insert into AllowPermission  
    values(@PermissionRoleID, @View, @Edit, @PermissionAccessoageID)
END
```

Comment: Please explain better your requirements

Comment: When i Inserted data to database. I want these (@RoleID,@IsActive ,@PermissionRoleID )3 columns first time only it should insert into database next time should not insert this 3 column into database. how can i achieve that.

Comment: The stored procedure is pretty useless in this context. Remove it and execute the query directly in code. In this way you could differentiate between the first loop and the following ones with a simple variable.

Comment: How about check those values in stored procedure before you insert them, just insert if not exists

Answer (score 0):

Change Procedure  to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE add3tables
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @RoleID nvarchar(50),
    @PermissionRoleID nvarchar(50),
    @IsActive bit,
    @View bit,
    @Edit bit,
    @PermissionAccessoageID nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

   IF  Not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Roles
                  WHERE Name=@Name and RoleID=@RoleID and IsActive=@IsActive)
begin      
  insert into Roles values(@Name, @RoleID, @IsActive) 
end 


    insert into AllowPermission  
    values(@PermissionRoleID, @View, @Edit, @PermissionAccessoageID)
END
```

Change column names of Roles table in if condition ,if different.